# WindowKeyPressFcn stops being called

Tags: matlab, user-interface, eeglab

I am working on some modifications to EEGlab's `eegplot` function (things like vim-style navigation etc.) that need to work through `WindowKeyPressFcn`.
However, the callback is not being called for some reason. I have been debugging the issue for some time and am a bit lost. I am looking for suggestions on what might be wrong. Unfortunatelly the `eegplot` function is big, complex and somewhat convoluted and I was unable to reproduce the issue in a simple example. Therefore I am looking for general suggestions on why a function handle that is clearly present in `WindowKeyPressFcn` might stop being used at some point.

Here is what I have learned so far:

- If I go to debug mode in `eegplot` (set a breakpoint near the end of the setup function [the first half of eegplot]) I am able to run the `WindowKeyPressFcn` at least once.
- However - the function stops being called at some point during debug (sometimes even after being called only once).
- If I run `eegplot` without debug (that is wait for it to finish and return control to me) I am unable to call `WindowKeyPressFcn` by pressing a key. The function handle is still present in `WindowKeyPressFcn` property of the figure.
- Whener the `WindowKeyPressFcn` is not being used when I press a key, I can still call it with:

  ```
  figh = gcf;
  fun = get(figh, 'WindowKeyPressFcn');
  ev.Key = 'rightarrow';
  ev.Character = ' ';
  ev.Modifier = [];
  feval(fun, figh, ev);
  ```

So the function handle is 'healthy' so to speak, but for some reason it is not being used any more when a key is pressed and the figure has focus. When and why something like this could happen? Any ideas on things I should check to understand this issue?

**Update**:
I found out that WindowKeyPressFcn callback can sometimes be blocked by some window listeners, and tried out the following solution:

```
hManager = uigetmodemanager(gcf);
set(hManager.WindowListenerHandles,'Enable','off');
```

It doesn't work - WindowKeyPressFcn is still not called when I press a key. :(

**Update 2**:
Another thing that does not work:

```
chld = get(gcf, 'Children');
tp = get(chld, 'type');
chld = chld(strcmp(tp, 'uicontrol'));
set(chld, 'KeyPressFcn', @eegplot_readkey_new)
```

(`eegplot_readkey_new` is the function I use for reacting to keypresses)

**Update 3**:
And another one not working:

```
addlistener(gcf, 'WindowKeyPress', @eegplot_readkey_new);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok - I fiugred it out, although the solution is weird to say the least.
For some mysterious reason using `linesmoothing` undocummented property prevents `WindowKeyPressFcn` from being called. I have absolutely no idea why...